# Are string literals automatically being casted to char* at compile time in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, types, compilation

If I were to do something like:

```
printf("The string is: %s\n", "string1");
```

Is the following done at compile time:

```
printf("The string is: %s\n", (unsigned char*) "string1");
```

Or similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is defined by the standard that the type of string literals is an array of `char`<sup>1</sup> and arrays automatically decay to pointers, i.e. `char*`. You don't need to cast it explicitly while passing it as an argument to `printf` when `%s` specifier is used.

Side note: In C++ it's `const char*`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> C99 6.4.5: *"A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in
double-quotes, as in "xyz"... **an array of static storage duration and length just
sufﬁcient to contain the sequence**. For character string literals, the array elements have
type `char`"*

<sup>[2]</sup> C++03 2.13.4 §1: *"an ordinary string literal has type “array of n
`const char`” and static storage duration"*

Comment: I see. It's just something that I knew must happen, but was curious as to how it's implemented; a typedef makes sense.

Comment: I see you're going to add a reference from the C standard, but it's not `const char *` under C.

Comment: Sorry to be ultra picky, but the type of the string literal itself is "array of `char`" most explicitly under C11 6.7.9.32, but also under C11 6.4.5.6. Obviously you are correctly that it will decay to `char *` under the usual circumstances. +1 for the references.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: No need to apologize. Check my answer now, it should be perfect :)

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is more or less correct, although the mechanism is different.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.  This is true for all array types, not just string literals.

The expression `"string1"` has type "8-element array of `char`"<sup>1</sup>; in the `printf` call it's not an operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, nor is it being used to initialize another array, so it is implicitly converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`"<sup>2</sup> whose value is the address of the first character.

---

<sup>1. 7 letters plus the 0 terminator.</sup>
<sup>2. This is the case in C; in C++, string literals are arrays of `const char`, so the expression will decay to type `const char *`.</sup>