# In char x[10]="hello" , why cout<<x; doesn't print out the array's address?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

As in

```
int x[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
cout<<x;
```

would print out x address. But if I choose character array, like

```
char x[10]="Hello";
```

it prints out the string

> Hello

And let's say compiler is smart enough to understand that in case of char array , it is point less to print out address and so it prints out the string instead, then how do I print char array address?

And consider this statement

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

Why is this legal, Aren't pointers supposed to store only address?

Comment: that is because the `operator<<(ostream&,T)` has an overload for `T=const char*` that prints the complete string and not just the adress (see e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2))

Comment: you may want `cout << static_cast<void *>(x);` instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19277635/168175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints "Hello" because `operator <<` has an overload for `const char*` (which is what you're passing if you pass `x`) that prints out a single `char` and moves to the next `char` until a NUL-character is found. "Hello" has a compiled-added NUL-character at the end, so your string is actually "Hello\0".

To get the address you can cast it to a `void*` to remove the overload of `const char*`:

```
reinterpret_cast<const void*>(x)
```

> Why is this legal, Aren't pointers supposed to store only address?

Yes, that's exactly what `ptr` is storing. When you assign a pointer to "Hello" which is a `const char[]` the ptr will point to `[0]` of that array. Note though that in this case a conversion first has to be made from `const char*` to `char*` which has been deprecated for years and is since C++11 illegal because trying to edit the pointee through this `char*` will lead to undefined behaviour. Some compilers still allow this though while really they should emit an error.

Comment: nitpicking/not sure about my english skills: isnt it " "Hello" is assigned to the pointer" instead of "a pointer is assigned to "Hello" " ?

Comment: yes....i was thinking the same @tobi303